# jQuery toggle CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I want to toggle between CSS so when a user clicks the button (`#user_button`) it shows the menu (`#user_options`) and changes the CSS, and when the user clicks it again it goes back to normal. So far this is all I have:

```
$('#user_button').click( function() {
    $('#user_options').toggle();
    $("#user_button").css({    
        borderBottomLeftRadius: '0px',
        borderBottomRightRadius: '0px'
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS snippets?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

For jQuery versions lower than 1.9 (see https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event):

```
$('#user_button').toggle(function () {
    $("#user_button").css({borderBottomLeftRadius: "0px"});
}, function () {
    $("#user_button").css({borderBottomLeftRadius: "5px"});
});
```

Using classes in this case would be better than setting the css directly though, look at the addClass and removeClass methods alecwh mentioned.

```
$('#user_button').toggle(function () {
    $("#user_button").addClass("active");
}, function () {
    $("#user_button").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This no longer works as this method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. See http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: But what if we have transition effect? in this case transition effect won't be applied, right?

Comment: This way it just adds the d-none (the boostrap class) to my div element, so I use `$('#user_button').toggleClass('active');` whenever button is clicked.

Answer (score 75):

I would use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function in jQuery and define the CSS to the class e.g.

```
/* start of css */
#user_button.active {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /* user-agent specific */
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px; /* etc... */
}
/* start of js */
$('#user_button').click(function() {
    $('#user_options').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    return false;
})
```

Comment: This is what I'd do too. Less styling in your JS then

Comment: Why is this not the answer?

Comment: @Ties - It definitely pays to be the first to post. It's a shame because it forcibly has a negative impact on the quality of answers. Better a quick response than a thorough one.

Comment: Both are right answers, just depends on the method you want to use. I like this one though, thanks

Comment: Anyone reading through this. Please consider using this answer before using the answer marked for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use jQuery's [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) commands, and create two different classes for the states. This, to me, would be the best practice way of doing it.

Comment: toggleClass is equivalent to these unless you want to remove a different class than you are adding for some reason

Answer (score 2):

The initiale code must have **borderBottomLeftRadius: 0px**

```
$('#user_button').toggle().css('borderBottomLeftRadius','+5px');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to set a class style in CSS like `.showMenu` and `.hideMenu` with the various styles inside. Then you can do something like

```
$("#user_button").addClass("showMenu");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by maintaining the state as below:

```
$('#user_button').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0);
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
      }
    else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1);
      $(this).css('background-color', 'orange')
    }
  });
```

[Take a reference from the codepen example here](https://codepen.io/pekul/pen/qwqVOm)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#toggle').active('click', function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").addClass("show");
    });

    $('#toggle .active').on('click', function(){
        $(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("hide");
    });

});
```

The Toggle menu has been closed and opened
but the Navigation item is not closed.

Comment: This answer seems very similar to the already accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#user_button').on('click', function() {
  $("#user_button").toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
#user_option.active {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This just repeats existing answers without any context or explanation.