# Toggle animation or Css

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, font-size

How can I toggle an animation or css change? For example I wanted a button that when pressed changes the font size then when pressed again it will change back. I could of course use two buttons, but It would be nice to have one button. I tried changing the id of the button right after changing the font size and then having a separate function for the new id to change it back, but that didn't seem to work.

Sorry, I'm new to Jquery :)

Thanks!

Comment: Never change ID's on the fly... ID's are mainly used for layout and must only be used at one place etc. (whole lot of reasons) . Use classes instead e.g. you can add multiple classes to a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a class for the style you want and use `toggleClass` to toggle the class.

Example usage

```
$(this).toggleClass('class');
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyP9A/)**

To animate include jQueryUI effects core and do this

```
$(this).toggleClass('large', delay);
```

**[Animation Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fyP9A/3/)**

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm! Btw is their a source url for the effects core that one can link to without including it in the root folder?

Comment: @user676610 go here http://jqueryui.com/download and you should be able to pick the effects core. Or just put this in the script src attribute http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 1):

possibly a repeat of this [jQuery toggle CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){

    if (!$('.targetContainer').hasClass('bigFont'))
    $('.targetContainer').addClass('bigFont');
    else
    $('.targetContainer').removeClass('bigFont');

    });
});
```

Comment: basically setting up the event on the button. Check if the target container has the class style you want to add, if not - set class and if it has - remove class.

Comment: Why not just use toggleClass instead of creating your own?

Comment: For more control, I never use toggle...especially with the animation.. coz clicking it quite quickly causes a bug.

Answer (score 0):

learn jQuery first changing of CSS can be done using toggle function.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

`$('button').click(function() {
  $('this').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});`