# jquery to toggle a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, toggle

How can I get the label to toggle show/hide? Below is my code and currently it is also displaying show. I would like it to toggle from show to hide and from hide back to show. when show is displayed the div will be hidden but when show is clicked the label will switch to hide and the div will be displayed and when hide is clicked the label will go back to show and the div will be hidden

```
  <html>
 <head>
<title>jQuery test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
 $("#textBox").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label id="clickMe">Show</label>
<br />
<div id="textBox" style="display: none">This text will be toggled</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question right, then I think the following would work:

```
$('#clickMe').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#textBox').show();
                $('#clickMe').text('hide');
            },
            function(){
                $('#textBox').hide();
                $('#clickMe').text('show');
            });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sQvpQ/).

If you use the attribute `for`, to define the element to which the `label` 'connects', and also use class-names, then this can be made more generic and useful:

```
$('.clickMe').toggle(
            function(){
                $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).show();
                $(this).text('hide');
            },
            function(){
                $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).hide();
                $(this).text('show');
            });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sQvpQ/1/).

Bear in mind, though, that the `label` element is used to associate information with specific `input` elements, as opposed to a generic identifier for arbitrary elements. Ideally, you should use a `span`, or `div`, element rather than a `label` for this purpose.

If you do switch to using non-`label` elements, then the `for` attribute shouldn't be used either, in its place I'd suggest (assuming the same connection between what's currently the `label` and the `div`) using a custom `data-*` attribute (such as `data-for`) to identify the relationship.

Note, also, in the above -final- example, the use of the `class` instead of the `id` selector, since an `id` ***must be unique*** within the document.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Toogle with callback feature: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Then you can set the text for the label in each callback.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455229/the-proper-use-of-jquery-toggle) here talks about the different toggle api calls.

Answer (score 0):

add the code below before or after your toggle.

http://jsfiddle.net/UuADb/

```
label = $(this);
if(label.html()=="Show"){
    label.html('Hide');
}else{
    label.html('Show');
}
```