# Toggle between two DIVs on click of image

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

Experts

My requirement is  to  have a display the total registration lines on my jsp and a user can also edit those on click of an image next to it, 
To display the total registration lines Im using the following jpeg 
[image]
Display a pencil next to the total using the code as

```
<div class="row-fluid" id ="result">
        <div class ="span2">
            <label><spring:message code='total.registration' />:</label>
        </div>
        <div class = "span3">
            ${registrationStatusForm.totalRegis}
            <img src="/static/img/icon_pensil.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and when a user clicks on the pencil next to the value displayed, an additional textbox should appear as below 
[image]
On click of a pencil , a user should be able to edit the total and the icons are different as shown above.

on click of a X , the user should again see the 1st image.

Please suggest a suitable way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: http://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jquery. You can simply hide/display elements with

```
$('#element_id').show() 
$('#element_id').hide().
```

So for example, if you want to show a new div when they click on an image, listen for a click event:

```
$('#pencil_picture_id').click(function(){
  $('#text_box').show();
});
```

EDIT: forgot parentheses

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
  $('your selector').toggle();
});
```