# How do I trigger an onclick CSS on a particular ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, triggers

I am trying to trigger a particular CSS on a particular ID, but it is effecting only one of the image of that ID, and not all the images with that ID.
Also, how do I roll back the changes if I click again on the same trigger?

This is the HTML I am using.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="https://imagesonline.bl.uk/coo/user/gpimages/Images_Online_Cooliris_Logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="http://www.niemanlab.org/images/getty-images-logo.png" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="http://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1119b.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="http://www.niehs.nih.gov/news/newsroom/releases/2013/august19/tbbpa_image_.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="http://learningdesign.psu.edu/themes/site_themes/agile_records/images/uploads/LDImages/itsupport2.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" class="img-responsive" id="some" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 tac">
            <br><br><br><button>test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hello world!

And this is the javascript I am using.

```
<script>
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('#some').css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'color': 'white',
        'font-size': '44px',
        'opacity': '0.1'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Id should be unique use classes instead

Comment: Thanks @Akshay that worked! Can you please tell me how can I roll back the changes to normal if I click the same trigger again?

Comment: You can try `toggleClass()` instead

Comment: @KristieMatthew See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css).

Comment: Hmm, if it's not too much, can you please show me how can I implement it? I am new to JS..

Comment: @KristieMatthew A simple demonstration click on the image http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/hpunwwz6/

Comment: I am clicking on the button in your jsfiddle link, the image isn't rotating? @Akshay

Comment: @KristieMatthew Click the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `class` instead of `id` for multiple element. for roleback you can use [`Toggle Class | jQuery UI`](https://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) Try as below:

```
<style>
    .active{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-size: 44px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
</style>
```

**JS**

```
$('#image').click(function() {
    $('.img-responsive').toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Note:** There should not be same `id` for multiple element in single page otherwise it will always consider first one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you need to use UNIQUE `ids`. Instead use a `class` :

```
$('.img-responsive').css({
    'background-color': 'black',
    'color': 'white',
    'font-size': '44px',
    'opacity': '0.1'
});
```

Also, never use duplicate `ids`, IDs are meant to be **unique** throughout the document.

If you want to rollback the changes use  classes instead. There are other approaches, but I feel this one is the best.

CSS:

```
.class1{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 44px;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
```

Jquery:

```
$('.img-responsive').toggleClass('class1');
```

Comment: Thanks @zee. Can you please tell me how do I roll back the changes?

Comment: <script>
 $('#image').click(function() {
    $('.img-responsive').css({
    'background-color': 'black',
    'color': 'white',
    'font-size': '44px',
    'opacity': '0.1'
});
});
</script>

Will this be the final script I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#image').click(function() {
   $('.img-responsive').css({
   'background-color': 'black',
   'color': 'white',
   'font-size': '44px',
   'opacity': '0.1'
  });
});
```

And to rollback just Use this code:

```
$(".img-responsive").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: While this will work, but this will also remove other inline styles if any.

Comment: Yes...but OP doesnot have any other requirement than this :D

Answer (score 0):

To rollback to the previous state try using jquery's toggle method

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

you can pass two functions in the toggle method as parameters and jquery will call each method one at a time.

[jQuery click / toggle between two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions)

check the link for more help and an example.