# Making div invisible and visible using toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div where when you click it, it's suppose to turn invisible, and when you click on it again, it's suppose to turn visible. But something's wrong with my code. Please take a look:

```
<div id = "id"> Hello </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

//*****************************************************************************

function toggleOnClick($id){

$("#"+$id).click(function() {   
$("#"+$id).toggle(

function () {
$(this).css({visibility: "hidden"});
}, 
function () {
$(this).css({visibility: "visible"});

}); //end of $("#"+$id).toggle

}); //end of $("#"+$id).click(function()    

} //end of function toggleOnclick($id)

//*****************************************************************************

$(document).ready(function(){

toggleOnClick("id");

});         

</script>
```

P.S: Got my source from the accepted answer in this link: [jQuery toggle CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tggle()` will toggle between `display` property so it will not retain place for element after it hides, You need to use `css()` with callback and update its `opacity`, it will retain it's place.

**Update :**  The click event will not fire on element with `visibility: hidden` so you need to use `opacity:0`

> Callback in `css()`  is a function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments. ( Taken from http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function )

```html
<div id="id">Hello</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //*****************************************************************************

  function toggleOnClick($id) {

      $("#" + $id).click(function() {
        $("#" + $id).css('opacity', function(i, v) {
          return v == 0 ? 1 : 0; //end of $("#"+$id).toggle
        });
      }); //end of $("#"+$id).click(function()    

    } //end of function toggleOnclick($id)

  //*****************************************************************************

  $(document).ready(function() {

    toggleOnClick("id");

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain the callback? And what's inside it?

Comment: Also the callback function have 2 parameters. 'i' and 'v', but I don't see the 'i' anywhere. What does it do?

Comment: @jessica : i is index and v is old value

Comment: @jessica :  we don't need i , but we want v

Comment: Why is i included in the parameter if we don't need it? o.O

Comment: ...And I understand that. So I'm asking you why you're including the first parameter 'i', if we only need the second parameter 'v'.

Comment: So you're saying the first parameter 'i' is needed, but we're just never going to use it. It's only going to be used as an index for something? Okay.

Comment: Also. I've just read the api.query's definition for the callback function and it's confusing me a bit. Can you describe it in layman's terms? And also, can you describe in details what this part of the code does? return v == 0 ? 1 : 0;

Comment: it's shorthandler for if else statement... if v(old value) equals 0 then it returns 1 else it will return 0

Comment: I see. That's all I need for now. I'll accept your answer now.