# toggling css with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change css with only one onclick function

```
$('#hamburger').on('click',function(){

    $('nav').toggle(1000);

    $('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom','30px');
        $('h5').toggle(1000);
    });
```

I want when I click again to show

```
 $('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom','104px');
```

So first time when I click `#hamburger` I want my `col-md-3` padding bottom 30px,and when I click again and close `#hamburger` I want my `col-md-3` padding bottom should be 104px.

How to do that?

Comment: how to identify when the hamburger is open? there should be some distinguishing factor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Answer (score 0):

One dirty way:

```
$('#hamburger').on('click',function(){
 $('nav').toggle(1000);

 // check for existing css values
 if ($('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom') === '30px') {
  $('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom', '104px');
 } else {
  $('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom', '30px');
 }

 $('h5').toggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the current padding of the element and set the new padding based on that - if it's 30px, set it to 104px and vice versa.

```
$('#hamburger').on('click',function(){
  $('nav').toggle(1000);
  $('h5').toggle(1000);

  var padding = $('.col-md-3').css('padding-bottom')
  $('.col-md-3').css(
    'padding-bottom', (padding === '30px')? '104px' : '30px'
  );
});
```