# CSS transitions by adding and removing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the below code snippet I have a vertical sidebar that can become wider when a TOGGLE button is clicked. The Sidebar eases in with an animation and additionally displays the description text when the sidebar is wide. I think I achieved all of this properly.

My concern is more about my code. It doesn't feel right. Is there anyway I can do this all with simply adding and removing css classes?

Additionally, I would like advice on the way I am using delay to make sure when the extra description text appears it doesn't look horrible.

```js
var menuSize = 'Small';

$(".js-menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (menuSize == 'Small') {
    $('#sidebar').css('width', '180px');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '180px');

    $('#sidebar').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-ms-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-o-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#app-wrapper').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#app-wrapper').css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#app-wrapper').css('-ms-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#app-wrapper').css('-o-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#app-wrapper').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease');

    $('.menu-item-desc').delay(120).show(0);

    menuSize = 'Large'
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').css('width', '50px');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '50px');

    $('#sidebar').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-ms-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('-o-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#sidebar').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('-ms-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('-o-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
    $('#content-wrapper').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease');

    $('.menu-item-desc').hide();

    menuSize = 'Small'
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #102027;
  color: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#header-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#subheader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #37474f;
  color: #fff;
  clear: right;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-top: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu-item-desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar">
  <a class="js-menu-toggle" href="#">TOGL</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 1 Desc</span></li>
    <li>Item 2<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 2 Desc</span></li>
    <li>Item 3<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 3 Desc</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container-fluid">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container-fluid">PRIMARY CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What's the trouble?

Comment: Why not try it before coming here to confirm?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I did try it using jQuery addClass and nothing works...

Comment: @DanielBeck Alright, will post it now.

Comment: Have you explored declaring `transition` rules on the elements that will change, like `#sidebar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in some other answers (I noticed after writing my code), you could use jQuery's toggleClass function to achieve this.

```js
$(".js-menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#sidebar").toggleClass("expanded");
  $("#content-wrapper").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

```css
html,
body 

{
  height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #102027;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
#sidebar.expanded {
   width: 180px;
}
#sidebar .menu-item-desc {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
}
#sidebar .menu-item-desc:hover{
   display: block;
}
#sidebar.expanded .menu-item-desc {
   opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
#sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#content-wrapper.expanded {
    margin-left: 180px;
}
#header-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#subheader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #37474f;
  color: #fff;
  clear: right;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-top: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar">
  <a class="js-menu-toggle" href="#">TOGL</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 1 Desc</span></li>
    <li>Item 2<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 2 Desc</span></li>
    <li>Item 3<span class="menu-item-desc"> - Item 3 Desc</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container-fluid">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container-fluid">PRIMARY CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I love this example, however the opacity 0 technique is messing up my UI since the menu-item-desc is actually taking up space on the page. If the user puts their cursor to the right side of the small version of the menu it will cause a hover on the li because their cursor is technically over top of the menu-item-desc. Is there anyway I can get the best of both worlds? The opacity effect without the menu-item-desc taking up space when opacity=0?

Comment: You could use an animation to set it to display: none after the opacity reaches 0.

Comment: would I do this by creating another class that does the animation or sets the display none?

Comment: thank you. So it was a matter of using Visibility: visible and hidden on the .menu-item-disc classes correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! Use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) accordingly.

For example, the `#sidebar` element can have a class assigned to it:

```
.toggle-slidein {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

In your jQuery you can apply it like so:

```
$('#sidebar').addClass('toggle-slidein');
```

That takes care of these lines of code:

```
$('#sidebar').css('-webkit-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
$('#sidebar').css('-moz-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
$('#sidebar').css('-ms-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
$('#sidebar').css('-o-transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
$('#sidebar').css('transition', 'all 0.3s ease');
```

You can extend this to the rest of your code as you see fit.

**Edit**: providing `toggleClass` example for `sidebar` and `content-wrapper`:

First add some CSS classes that will represent the changes to the elements you want to dynamically change.

```
.sidebar--large {
  width: 180px;
}
.content-wrapper--pushleft {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

Then in your jQuery:

```
$(".js-menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (menuSize == 'Small') {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar--large');
    $('#content-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper--pushLeft');
    //... other code
    menuSize = 'Large';

  } else {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar--large');
    $('#content-wrapper').toggleClass('content-wrapper--pushLeft');
    //... other code
    menuSize = 'Small';
  }
}
```

The jQuery code using `toggleClass` creates a *toggle effect* by checking for the specified class name; so the class names are added if missing, and removed if already set on the element.

Comment: You wouldn't toggle the transition styles, only the width style

Comment: I changed it to `addClass` to provide a more concrete example

Comment: @Age this is exactly what I needed. Is there anyway I can improve the changing of the width and margin-left of the sidebar and content-wrapper?

Comment: @BlakeRivell certainly, using `toggleClass`. I can provide an example by editing my answer

Comment: @AGE if you can do that it would be awesome. So far your answer has helped me the most because it is most descriptive.

Comment: @BlakeRivell there you go

Answer (score 0):

Woo buddy! That's a lot of CSS you have in your Javascript! Yes, you can simply put all of that into a CSS class and then add/remove said class dynamically in your Javascript. Check out this question that should answer what you're looking for :)

[Here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you create classes with your required css styles, you can then toggle them with jquery:

`$('#sidebar').toggleClass('class-name', true)` adds the class
`$('#sidebar').toggleClass('class-name', false)` removes the class

Simply add classes for each menu size and add/remove them as required inside the event.

Comment: do the transitions go on the classes or on the divs?

Comment: The transitions should be included with classes. I would suggest creating classes for each element, depending on the menu size.

For instance, create a `.sidebar-large` class which you can then toggle on if the sidebar is large. Add the transitions to this `.sidebar-large` class.

Comment: The transition should be a standard rule of the element in question, in any state that it is in, the classes you add and remove should have the position/size changes declared.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError If I do this and .sidebar-large class has a width of 180px and I create a content-wrapper large class with a margin-left of 180px will this override the original div styles? That is my concern.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Sure, it should just be a simple matter of specificity, so make sure that you have the right selectors declared to over-qualify default styles.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question I think what you are looking for is .toggleClass method in jquery or you can use .addClass and .removeClass I have supplied links for it here:

- [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
- [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) / [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: what class would I be toggling. A class that changes the width and margin of my elements or a class that has the transitions?

Comment: Firstly you need to have the code of your transition/change of margin etc. and then use the .toggleClass function. I am not quit sure if what I told you helps you. Let me know though! Hope I helped you.