# How to toggle style on elements

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use a button to toggle some **style** *on and off* for some selected elements. I can *add* the style, like so:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".elements").each(function() {
        var height = $(this).data("height");
        $(this).css({ 'height': height, 'background-color': "#ccc" });
    });
 });
```

However, I'm not sure how to toggle the style to "off" (remove the styling I have just applied).

I've tried to use the following solution ([jQuery toggle CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)), but I'm not sure that it will work in this case as I'm using a function to gather a style attribute from within the `data` attribute of each element.

What would be the best way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: To disable css you simply set the styles back to their default or desired values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery toggle CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337621/jquery-toggle-css)

Comment: This is old-school way for toggling: https://jsfiddle.net/e9popoet/1/ However, not sure about default style (and where it is defined)...maybe all could be simplified.

Comment: @sinisake you can just do `flag = !flag` at the end of the loop

Answer (score -1):

You are making it unnecessarily complex. Just set a default style, then toggle a class with a different styling. See the example below.

```js
$(function () {

$("[type=button]").click(function () {

$("div").toggleClass("otherClass");

});
});
```

```css
* {
margin: auto;
width: 100px
}

div {
height: 100px;
background: red;
margin-bottom: 25px;
transition: all 2s;
color: white;
line-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

.otherClass {
background: green;
transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The DIV</div>

<input type="button" value="Toggle Style" >
```

Comment: There is one problem - height is defined in data attribute, for each element, so every element will have different height...

Comment: @sinisake In that case, the height should be left as is. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, I'm looking to set a variable height on each element using a value from the data attribute. There is no height beforehand, but the height is added after clicking the button.

Comment: @inersha I think you should provide more information!